# How to test an Angular JS UI App, end to end testing using Mocha framework

Tags: node.js, angular, mocha.js, angular-e2e

I need to perform end to end test for Node.js front end Application developed using AngularJs 4. Currently we are using Mocha framework for Nodejs Rest API services. Can we use Mocha framework for testing Node.js front end Application developed using AngularJs 4??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Protractor` as the e2e testing framework for testing the UI of the `nodejs` application. Be default, `Protractor` uses `jasmine` but it allows you to use `mocha` as the framework of choice, for your tests. It's pretty easy and straightforward to set up.

I suggest `Protractor` because it has built in synchronization and locators specific to Angular, which gives a lot of flexibility. You can also use `Nightwatch` and `WebDriverio` as well, but not sure if they'll let you keep `mocha` as framework.

You can combine `Protractor`, `mocha` and use `chai` as the assertion framework for the end to end tests, and also include `Cucumber JS` if you're looking for a BDD testing suite.

Example : I created [this](https://github.com/zac11/yarn-cucumber-ts) demo repository a while ago. It combines `Protractor`, `TypeScript`, `CucumberJS` and `Mocha` with `Chai` as assertion framework. This is based on this [fantastic](https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript) framework by Ram Pasala

Comment: If possible, can you provide a link with an example of combining Protractor, mocha and using chai. It would be helpful